# Create Member who can't be changed

Tags: password, membership

we need on single account which we may share with a group of people. we don't want that tey are able to change anything (password, name). They sould only view some protected information. We can't use possword protection, because this is to insecure (keeps saved in browser for 10 days).

Here is what I found:

`add_action( 'load-profile.php', 'd_disable_editing_my_profile' );` - to prevent changing profile
`add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_default_page');` - to redirect users

What did not work for us: prevent password-reset link only for this users + redirect other users to dashboard instead main page.

Is there a plugin or something else that could solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is really hacky but you could just hide those fields with `css` and toggle them as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm not feeling secure to just hide them with css. Since Wordpress is OpenSource, the one or other interested person would surely notice this quickly.